# How to parse the table using jsoup with java

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to parse this table using jsoup.  I tried `select("tr")`, but this also picks up the last table row with the style. 
Can any one help me in this case? I am using Java with jsoup .

```
<tr>
       <td> one </td>
       <td> two </td>
       <td> three </td> 
</tr>

<tr>
        <td>four</td>
        <td>five</td>
        <td>six</td>    
</tr>

<tr style="display:none">
        <td> NO MORE </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you post your [code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

to select only tr elements without style you could do this:

```
Elements trs = doc.select("tr:not([style])");
```